# Find the value of $a+b+c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

If $$3.\sqrt{5.\sqrt[3]{37}-16}=\sqrt[3]a-\sqrt[3]b-c$$
What is the value of $a+b+c$?
**EDIT**: I forgot to mention that $a$, $b$ and $c$ are positive integers.

> I tried squaring and then cubing but it got very lengthy. Is there some elegant method to do it?

Comment: Do you mean $3\cdot \sqrt{5\sqrt[3]{37} - 16} = \sqrt[3]{a} - \sqrt[3]{b} - c$?

Comment: Where did this problem come from?

Comment: When typing more than a character under the square root bracket, be sure to type for instance \sqrt[3]{37} instead of \sqrt[3]37.  \sqrt[3]{37} gives $\sqrt[3]{37}$ whereas \sqrt[3]37 gives $\sqrt[3]37$

Comment: @NasuSama Thanks! I made the edit.

Comment: @mixedmath I saw it in an algebra book in my school library. I forgot to see the name of  the book.

Comment: I don't think this problem is well-posed. For example, you might take $a=0,b=0,c=-3\sqrt{5\sqrt[3]{37} - 16}$ or $a=(3\sqrt{5\sqrt[3]{37} - 16})^3,b=0,c=0$, which both satisfy the equation (unless I'm missing something), but the sums $a+b+c$ differ: one is negative and one is positive. Should we assume that $a,b,c$ are integers or something like that?

Comment: Are the numbers supposed to be integers - otherwise you can take $a$ as large as you like, $b=0$ and c large too.

Comment: @DejanGovc Yeh, sorry I made the correction :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $\theta=\sqrt[3]{37}$. If we put $\alpha=\theta^2-2\theta-2 \approx 2.4$, then

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
\alpha^2 &=& (\theta^2-2\theta-2)^2 \\
&=&  \theta^4 - 4 \theta^3 + 8 \theta + 4 \\
&=&  37\theta -4\times 37+8\theta+4 \\
&=& 45\theta -144 \\
&=& 9(5\theta-16)
\end{array}
$$

It follows that $3\sqrt{5\theta-16}=\alpha$, so
$a=37^2,b=8\times 37,c=2$, and hence $a+b+c=1667$.

Comment: Wow! Really elegant method. Thanks!